# Lottie Web: play 2 animations in the same canvas at the same time

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, lottie

I am new to Lottie and am wondering how to play 2 animations side by side at the same time in the same canvas element on the Web.

I have followed this example[1] and then the advice given here[2] with regards to transforming the canvas on every frame to position either animation respectively.

What I would like to achieve is this: 2 red balls bouncing side by side on the same canvas. One playing at x = 0 and one playing at x = 100 on the same canvas.

Here is my approach in a CodePen[3]. I extracted the JS for visibility.

```js
      const testjson = {...animation...};
      const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
      const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

      // Drawing sth on the context to see whether sharing works
      ctx.fillStyle = "green";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);

      function renderAnimation(canvasContext, translation) {
        const animData = {
          renderer: "canvas",
          loop: true,
          rendererSettings: {
            context: canvasContext,
            clearCanvas: true,
          },
          animationData: testjson,
        };

        const anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData);
        
        // Transform the canvas for the respective animation on enter-frame
        anim.addEventListener("enterFrame", () => {
          ctx.translate(translation.x, translation.y);
        });

        // If efective, causes onion-effect
        // anim.setSubframe(false);
      }

      renderAnimation(ctx, { x: 0, y: 0 });
      renderAnimation(ctx, { x: 100, y: 0 });
```

Alas, the way I implemented it does not seem to work.
Does anybody know what I am missing?

Thank you!

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/RenanSgorlom/pen/orgxyJ
[2]: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/1671
[3]: https://codepen.io/user1207504/pen/MWVYvxd
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that much code to have some balls bouncing on the same canvas ...
Certainly no need for a library to just do that.

The balls we can draw using `arc` functions:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc

- movement is to increase the position on x or y, in the code is the `x += vx`
- bouncing we just change the direction, you can see it in my code `vx *= -1`

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class ball {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data
  }
  draw() {
    this.data.x += this.data.vx
    this.data.y += this.data.vy
    if (this.data.x > canvas.width || this.data.x < 0) this.data.vx *= -1
    if (this.data.y > canvas.height || this.data.y < 0) this.data.vy *= -1
    
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.fillStyle = this.data.color
    ctx.arc(this.data.x,this.data.y, this.data.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill()
  }
}

const balls = [
  new ball({x: 10, y: 10, vx: 0, vy: 1, radius: 8, color: "pink" }),
  new ball({x: 90, y: 90, vx: 0, vy: -1, radius: 8, color: "red" }),
  new ball({x: 5, y: 50, vx: 1, vy: 1.5, radius: 8, color: "cyan" })
]
 
function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  balls.forEach(b => b.draw())
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

animate()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you ver much for this neat demo, @Helder! I totally agree - if this was only about bouncing balls, your code would be a great solution. However, I need this to work for Lottie animations (which often have shape transforms etc - balls were only used as an example animation). Do you happen to know how how multiple of those could be combined on the same canvas using context translation (not using the SVG [preserveAspectRatio modes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio))?

Comment: I use context translation sparingly and for what you are describing there is no need for that, you can make any shape or animation you want, just change what happens in the draw... but if you insist on using lottie, maybe go with two overlapping canvases